# Bootstrap: How to get part of my banner image to hide under my sidebar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Working my first Twitter Bootsrap project. It's been a while since I've used CSS/HTML, so bear with me. My question is:

How do I get the left side of my banner image to go under my sidebar menu column? The sidebar column texture is a transparent png. I'm sure it's a simple fix...but I can't think of it right now! Help! :)

Here's [my page](http://www.ogmda.com/test/menu.html).

Comment: Kindly post the offending code for review as it may help others when the link inevitably leads nowhere relevant. Thanks!

Comment: Just cut the image with some image manipulation program, or specify the width property in `<img>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real simple solution is to put the banner image behind the parent container and align it right. It doesn't need its own div, and you won't have to crop the image in any way.

You will also need to adjust the right column with some top padding so that it doesn't overlap the image.

---

**Updated**

Here's some code to help you out.
Change:

```
<section class="row menuPage">
    <aside class="span3 sidebar">...</aside>
    <section class="span9">
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <article>...</article> 
    </section>
</section>
```

to

```
<section class="row menuPage">
    <aside class="span3 sidebar">...</aside>
    <section class="span9">
        <article>...</article> 
    </section>
</section>
```

And add the following CSS declaration (targeting the first child in the container):

```
.section.menuPage {
    url("img/banner2.png") no-repeat scroll right top #1C0F0A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I think you're looking for something like this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/w3pR4/1/embedded/result/
- http://jsfiddle.net/w3pR4/ (code)

Basically all I did was move the banner outside of the span grid of your main column into it's own span. In other words, it was previously nested under a `span9`, I simply relocated it to be above both columns and gave it it's own `span12` to maintain some semblance of responsiveness (note the responsiveness in the fiddle likely won't work).

[image]